sharing a python object in realtime between socketIO and flask app
I'm working with a web app that is based on socketIO and flask. The problem is that i have a shared object that is changed when a post request is done. However, these changes are not always visible when socketio.emit is called.
Specifically I have a similar situation:
script socket_script.py
from helper import classA
from flaskapp_script import flask_routes

app.register_blueprint(flask_routes)
    
while True:
    if classA.state == 'decoding':
           
        roi_object = classA.rois

     else:
         roi_object = None
     socketio.emit('data_updated', roi_object)


script flaskapp_script.py
from helper import classA

flask_routes = Blueprint('http_test', __name__)

@flask_routes.route("/detect", methods=["GET","POST"])
def detect():
    
    classA.state = 'decoding'
    for i in range(len(classA.rois)):
       classA.rois['processed'] = True


Considering the reported example, the problem is that classA.rois (which is a list), sometimes results not updated in socket_script.py.
Any explanation related to this behaviour? How do you suggest to solve this problem?
Consider that classA is already defined as single instance as it follows:
script helper.py
class classA_def:
def __init__(self):
    self.rois = [{'id': 0,'processed':False},{'id': 1,'processed':False}, ....] 
    
def dosomething(self):
    print('doing something')
    return

classA = classA_def()
I already compared carefully what happens to classA.rois list in the two files...
